# Issue Referencing A Worksheet as A Collection Field

Tags: blueprism

I have a collection which is gotten from a worksheet. However, when I try to reference a column name it tells me that the column doesn't exist in the collection. If I change this column name to a one worded heading such as company it works fine. Is this to do with the excel file itself or a bug in Blueprism?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's some trailing spaces in your source file's column headings. When referencing the column, make sure to include these trailing spaces.

Alternatively, do some preprocessing on the source document to trim the leading and trailing spaces before importing the data to a collection.

Comment: Thanks, when I add a trailing space I still get the message The field 'Invoice_Number' doesn't exist within this collection. It doesn't look to be including the trailing space. Is there a way that I can trim the trailing spaces from all the column headings in the collection? Either when I import or as a later step?

Comment: The error *"The field 'Invoice_Number' doesn't exist within this collection"* indicates to me that you haven't actually entered the field's name with a trailing space. I'd expect *"The field 'Invoice_Number ' doesn't exist within this collection"* (note the extra space before the close quote on Invoice_Number)

Comment: Alternatively: loop through all columns in your header row and apply the calculation stage function `Trim()` to the value, and set the trimmed value back to the cell.

Comment: Another alternative: use a custom code stage to expand your default Collection Manipulation VBO to loop through all columns and apply a `Trim()` to their names.